# Anyway to Speed up this code?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics

I have the following code:

```
SampleDistanceHist[one_, two_] := Module[{},
  dst1 = HistogramDistribution[one];
  dst2 = HistogramDistribution[two];
  Plus @@ Table[(CDF[dst1, x] - CDF[dst2, x])^2, {x, -1,1, 0.001}]}]]
```

this is  distance function(sum of squared difference of 2 CDFs) to solve the minimization problem.(Approximation of probability distribution)

but this is slow in operation.
Is there any way to speed up this code?

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `dist2` in the second `CDF`?

Comment: you're right. thanks!

Comment: Last line is full of syntax errors.

Comment: thank you for pointing out. but tell me what is wrong. the following code works correctly (of course,my code is not perfect.)
f1 = Sin[x];
f2 = Cos[x];
Plus @@ Table[(f1 - f2)^2, {x, -1, 1, 0.0001}]

Comment: Wouldn't integration work? For example, `NIntegrate[ (CDF[dist1, x] - CDF[dist2, x])^2, {x, -1, +1}]` is faster than your `Table`. Of course, one has to work out the limits correctly or go from -infinity to +infinity. There are lots of options to "tweak" the speed of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[sampleDistanceHist]
sampleDistanceHist[one_, two_] := Module[{table = Range[-1, 1, .001],
   dst1 = HistogramDistribution[one], dst2 = HistogramDistribution[two], b, p, f1, f2},
  b = Join[{-1 + Min@#}, #, {1 + Max@#}] & /@ (#["BinDelimiters"] & /@ {dst1, dst2});
  p = Normalize[Accumulate[Join[{0, 0}, #["PDFValues"], {0}]], Max] & /@ {dst1, dst2};
  {f1, f2} = Interpolation[Transpose[{b[[#]], p[[#]]}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]&/@{1, 2};
  Total[Subtract[f1@table, f2@table]^2]]
```

Using the example data, `one` and `two` from Edmund's answer:

```
SeedRandom[1]
one = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
two = RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[5], 200];

SampleDistanceHist[one, two] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.20, 471.531}

```
sampleDistanceHist[one, two] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.011, 471.531}

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html).

With

```
one = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
two = RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[5], 200];
```

then

```
t = TransformedDistribution[(x - y)^2, 
   Thread[{x, y} \[Distributed] HistogramDistribution /@ {one, two}]];
```

and

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[t, 500]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! but in your code,what we do is something like Method of Moments not measuring the distance of Distribution itself?